# Can't install VS code properly due to blockage of extensionHost

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, installation

Please help me, I am trying to install VS code for 3 weeks but there's this problem where whenever it comes to the point of installing extension host and some other main file, it says installation failed, and then there's a notification saying 'Successfully Repaired JS.nemucod.ad', and it asks me if i want to skip the installation of extension Host, and I skip, because retrying never works, then after VS code installs, I check the app and find out that nothing is working, the whole screen is black, this was just 1 day ago, before that it used to install the main file without any problems, but it still used to raise an error while installing extension host.

I am sure this main file's absence is causing the black screen problem, but I am not sure how to fix any of this,

I hope you understand my question.

And i am using Windows 10.

Comment: Can you comment with the list of VS code extensions that are installed and you anti-virus software ?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any antivirus, I will download one soon, and about vs code extensions, I don't have any as this is my first time.

Comment: Hi, which version did you installed? Please go to the folder: C:\Users\{user name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node, check if the files extensionHostProcess.js and extensionHostWorker.js are exist or not.